# How to enable intel virtualization technology if it is disabled in intel processor identification utiity?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, virtualization, kali-linux, intel-core-i5

I have installed a virtual machine on Oracle virtual box, but it is showing black screen error with cursor, in logs, there was an issue as:
00:00:06.668127 HM: HMR3Init: Attempting fall back to NEM: VT-x is not available

Screeshot 1:
[In Bios setting intel virtualization is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JTka.jpg)

But later it was found that in Intel Processor Identification Utility, Intel Virtualization was disabled so, how to enable the same.
[Intel Processor Identifiaction Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm9vR.png)

[Black Screen error in virtual box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWJM9.png)

Comment: You enable Intel Virtualization in the BIOS.

Comment: Do you have Hyper-V, device guard, or credential guard enabled?  What antivirus do you have?  Some AV programs will block hardware VT.

Comment: Already enabled Intel virtualization in bios @harrymc

Comment: HyperV , credential guard both are disabled and I am not using any vendors antivirus software. @essjae

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved after switching off core isolation in device security under windows security option, now virtual machines are running perfectly fine. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

According to your BIOS screenshot, your computer model supports VT-d but not VT-x.

You need both VT-d and VT-x.

The full names by Intel are:

- Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d)
- Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT)